# Extending @Html.DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to use the following code by extending the `@Html.DropDownListFor` helper.
My controller gets a list, and I am adding a default value to the `IEnumerable` in my view model. However I don't want to write all of this every time I want a dropdown with a default value. So extending the helper seems logical.

```
public class SiteGetSitesViewModel
{
    public string SelectedSiteId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SiteListItems { get; set; }
}
public ActionResult GetSites()
{
    List<SiteDto> sites = _siteService.GetSites();
    const string defaultText = "Select a site";
    const string defaultValue = "-1";

    var siteGetSitesViewModel = new SiteGetSitesViewModel
        {
            SiteListItems = Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Selected = true,
                    Text = defaultText,
                    Value = defaultValue
                }, 1).Concat(sites.Select(s => new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = s.SiteName,
                        Value = s.SiteId.ToString()
                    }))
        };


    return PartialView("_GetSites", siteGetSitesViewModel);
}
```

Comment: Do you already know about class `SelectList`?  Is there a reason why you are not using it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Html.DropDownListFor` supports adding a default value to the choices already, so there is no need to reinvent the wheel:

Use this overload:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703567(v=vs.108).aspx

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.Property,
    GetSelectList(),
    "defaultOption", // the text for the default option goes here
    null
)
```

Comment: Correct is does, only if the item you want selected as default is in the list to start with. I don't want to add the default value to every List

Comment: Wrong - I use this to add a "Choose One" option to the list all the time.

Comment: so essentially what I want to do is create my own little overload and do the concat of the default item and passed in list.

Comment: Let me try it, I could not get that overload to work earlier.

Comment: you rock sir. I appreciate your time. As usual I was thinking to much about things :)

Comment: NP.  Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.SelectedSiteId,Model.SiteListItems,"Select a site",null) Is what I ended up with